# CloudKit "Deploy Schema to Production" throws error "There was a problem loading the environment's status"

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

I have been trying to do this for a few hours now but each time, it throws the error:

[image]

The web inspector tool in Safari shows this error:

'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)'

Comment: Same here - has been happening for me all day

Comment: @SteveB It wasn't working for me all day yesterday and earlier today. But now it worked fine automatically. So probably some issues on Apple's end.

Comment: Yep, back for me this morning.  Frustrating and occurring issue by the looks of it every few months.

Comment: @SteveB Yea, I noticed that too. A lot of other frustrated users every few weeks on Apple's developer forums.

Comment: I have this issue for three weeks now. Apple Support pointed me to https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/656723 which says "wait a few hours" and suggested to use a different schema (ignoring that customers might have data in the broken schema).